# Strange test result. My win32 program works slower when I am not using it

Tags: c++, winapi

I have done some tests with QueryPerformanceCounter and got strange results.
It seems that my simple program refreshes slowly (about 40ms) when it doing nothing, but when I put RedrawWindow with RDW_INVALIDATE message it refreshes and works very fast (about 1ms)

Please look at the examples:

{...}

```
double PCFreq = 0.0;
__int64 now = 0, start = 0;

LARGE_INTEGER li;

PCFreq = double(li.QuadPart)/1000;

AllocConsole( );  
freopen("CONOUT$", "wb", stdout);

double delay;

while (GetMessage (&messages, NULL, 0, 0))
{
        QueryPerformanceCounter(&li);    
        now = li.QuadPart;

        if ( double(now - start) / PCFreq >= 40)
        {
                **// painting !!!**

         cout <<  double(now - start) / PCFreq << "\n";
         start = now;
        }

        // !!!!!!
        **RedrawWindow(hwnd, NULL, NULL, RDW_VALIDATE);** 

        TranslateMessage(&messages);
        DispatchMessage(&messages);

    }

    FreeConsole( );
```

{...}

When the `RedrawWindow(hwnd, NULL, NULL, RDW_VALIDATE);` is in main loop I can obtain exacly 40ms or even 5ms, but without `RedrawWindow(hwnd, NULL, NULL, RDW_VALIDATE);` the condition if ( double(now - start) / PCFreq >= 40) is entering no faster than 45-50 ms....

My question is:
How can I avoid `RedrawWindow(hwnd, NULL, NULL, RDW_VALIDATE);` function but keep fast refreshing. When Iam using `RedrawWindow(hwnd, NULL, NULL, RDW_VALIDATE);` my interface (buttons, windows) not displays.

THANKS!

Comment: You're calling QueryPerformanceCounter only when there's messages to process. What are you trying to measure ?

Comment: Shall we assume that there's a call to QueryPerformanceFrequency somewhere so that PCFreq isn't 0?

Comment: QueryPerformanceCounter can be broken on multiprocessor systems you should probably be using timegettime instead.

Comment: @stonemetal: That's not true.

Comment: @Billy ONeal  So the remarks found here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644904(v=vs.85).aspx are wrong?  And the issues I have run into trying to use it in the real world are just figments of my imagination?

Comment: @StoneMetal: It's possible switching processors can cause `QueryPerformanceCounter` to be buggy if you happen to be one of the (extremely small) minority of machines with problems. `QueryPerformanceCounter` is designed for microbenchmarks, like the one indicated in this question. `timeGetTime` is neither accurate enough nor has high enough resolution for such benchmarks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GetMessage does not return unless there is a message in the message queue.  By calling RedrawWindow, you are putting a Message in the queue every single iteration of the loop.  Use PeekMessage instead of GetMessage:

```
while (true)
{
    if (PeekMessage(&messages, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
    {
        if (messages.message == WM_QUIT)
            break;
        TranslateMessage(&messages);
        DispatchMessage(&messages);
    }

    // Do your stuff here
}
```

Comment: `PeekMessage` returns a non-zero value when messages are available, not necessarily `TRUE`.

Comment: @PigBen - thanks, this is what I have been looking for! now works fine!

@nos and @Rob Kennedy - thanks, I am using this timer to obtain exactly 40ms (25 fps) - i must show my image buffer

Comment: @MSN: It returns type BOOL, and if it's anything other than TRUE or FALSE, the problem should be reported to Microsoft.

Comment: @PigBen, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644943(VS.85).aspx. It's documented right there in Return Value. And at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff381404(VS.85).aspx: "Despite this definition of TRUE, however, most functions that return a BOOL type can return any non-zero value to indicate Boolean truth."

Comment: @PigBen, yeah, one of the fun things working with `GetMessage(...)` is that it returns -1 on errors :).